# HTML - Body not centered?

Tags: html

i have a page here that seems to be the only page giving this problem, the body content which is the three options shown in the site for example: Daily, 3 days, and weekly, are not centering properly for some reason, ive tried adding the center tag to no avail. I have looked through the code and i cant see the error, maybe a second pair of eyes would find my problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Page Link: ~Snip~

```
<div class="container marg10">
        <div class="row">

                </ul>
            </div>
<center>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col3-box">
            <div class="plan featured">
              <div class="plan-head"><h3>Daily</h3><br>
              <div class="price">$15 <span>Per Day</span></div></div>
                <ul>
                  <li><b>No Automatic Bans</b></li>
                  <li class="two_plan"><b>KV's last weeks</b></li>
                  <li><b>XOSC Spoofing</b></li>
                  <li class="two_plan"><b>Custom Login Notification</b></li><br>
<p><input id="accept1" type="checkbox"> I have read and agree to the <a href="javascript:showToS();clicked = true;">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></p>
                  <li><form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" onsubmit="return confSubmit('accept1');">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="snip">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col3-box">
            <div class="plan featured">
              <div class="plan-head"><h3>3 Days</h3><br>
              <div class="price">$40 <span>3 Days</span></div></div>
                <ul>
                  <li><b>No Automatic Bans</b></li>
                  <li class="two_plan"><b>KV's last weeks</b></li>
                  <li><b>XOSC Spoofing</b></li>
                  <li class="two_plan"><b>Custom Login Notification</b></li><br>

<p><input id="accept2" type="checkbox"> I have read and agree to the <a href="javascript:showToS();clicked = true;">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></p>
                  <li><form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" onsubmit="return confSubmit('accept2');">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="snip">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col3-box">
            <div class="plan featured">
              <div class="plan-head"><h3>Weekly</h3><br>
              <div class="price">$70 <span>Per Week</span></div></div>
                <ul>
                  <li><b>No Automatic Bans</b></li>
                  <li class="two_plan"><b>KV's last weeks</b></li>
                  <li><b>XOSC Spoofing</b></li>
                  <li class="two_plan"><b>Custom Login Notification</b></li><br>

<p><input id="accept3" type="checkbox"> I have read and agree to the <a href="javascript:showToS();clicked = true;">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></p>

                  <li><form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" onsubmit="return confSubmit('accept3');">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="snip">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
</center>
  <div class="content">
  <div class="container">

  <div class="border"></div>

         <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="copy">
            <h6>The <span class="color">Mod Shop</span></h6>
            <p>Copyright &copy; The Mod Shop - </a><a href="index.html">Home</a> | <a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>| <a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</footer> 

<!-- JS -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.isotope.js"></script> <!-- Isotope for gallery -->
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script> <!-- prettyPhoto for images -->
<script src="js/jquery.cslider.js"></script> <!-- Parallax slider -->
<script src="js/modernizr.custom.28468.js"></script>
<script src="js/filter.js"></script> <!-- Filter for support page -->
<script src="js/cycle.js"></script> <!-- Cycle slider -->
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script> <!-- Flex slider -->

<script src="js/easing.js"></script> <!-- Easing -->
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Comment: always provide code...not mind readers here...jsffidle better...

Comment: Im sorry, i figured it would be easier for you guys to view the page source rather than me posting the entire code here but you are right i will do that now.

Comment: well you provide your html struchture but if you see your tags are using styles..try to provide that in further questions...provide always css, html, javascript if you are using some...try to view another question as a model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column widths for a row must add up to 12. Change your plan col widths to 4 each (3*4=12) and the footer should start on the new row:

```
<div class="row">
    <center>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col4-box">
        <!-- plan 1 content -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col4-box">
        <!-- plan 2 content -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col4-box">
        <!-- plan 3 content -->        
    </div>
    </center>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <center>
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <! footer content -->
    </div>
    </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that was the biggest issue that seems to be fixed now its always something so simple. Im gonna keep looking through to find out the centering issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey scott, did you notice what might have been causing the issue of the column not centering? Sorry, however i have been looking for about an hour straight and i still cant figure it out.

Comment: Oh sorry, i mean the actual content, for example if you look at the page, you will notice that the pricing options seem to be aligned to the left instead of centered with the rest of the content on the page, however i dont see anything specifying their alignment. Again im sorry for the the aggravation.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you so much and again im sorry. Wish i could upvote you again.